# Equations for blow-ups non-regular centers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $X = \textrm{Spec} A$ be a reasonable scheme and $I\subset A$ an ideal generated by a regular sequence. Then we have a full set of generators/relations for the blow-up of $X$ along $V(I)$.

Are there other situations where one can compute a presentation for the Rees algebra by hand? The schemes I'm interested are things like arithmetic surfaces.

References will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you have explicit equations, perhaps it's also worth playing with like Macaulay2.  http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.6/share/doc/Macaulay2/ReesAlgebra/html/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for a description of the defining equations of Rees algebras in commutative algebra. In general, this is a hard question. The complete intersection case can be generalized to ideals of linear type.

> Definition: Let $R$ be a ring. An ideal $I$ is call of linear type if $\operatorname{Sym} (I) \cong R[It].$

Huneke showed that

> (Huneke 1980) An ideal is generated by $d$-sequence, then it is of linear type.

I believe the book Arithematic of blowup algebras by Vasconcelos has good information and references of ideals of linear type. Also, there are other cases one can say a bit more about the defining equations of Rees algebras under additional assumptions.